# Function overload. The operation inside the function is the same. Do I have to rewrite everything?

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

I have a bunch of functions with input `x` and `y`. I allow input type to be either pass by reference (if it is already there) and pass by temporary input (using &&) (if not exist and need to create a temporary object).

Basically, I define and overload functions as follow

```
double foo(const std:::vector<int> & x, const std:::vector<int> &  y){
// Do something
}
double foo(const std:::vector<int> & x,std:::vector<int>&& y){
// Do something
}
double foo(std:::vector<int>&& x,const std:::vector<int> &  y){
// Do something
}
double foo(std:::vector<int>&& x,std:::vector<int>&& y){
// Do something
}
```

`//Do something`  is exactly the same but the only difference is the input type. Is there a way I can simplify the code without too much redundancy? I do not want to have `foo(std:::vector<int> x,std:::vector<int> y)` for memory issue.

EDIT:
Sometime I also have to modified the input a little bit. There may be a different subset of three types `std::vector<int> &,std::vector<int> &&,const std::vector<int> &` for `x` and `y`.

As point out by @AVH (thanks!), if it is just from `std::vector<int> &&,const std::vector<int> &`, `const std::vector<int> &` should suffice to do the job.

Combining both two answers by @Ken Wayne VanderLinde and @NathanOliver, I am able to write a function that restricted `y` to only `std::vector<int> &&,const std::vector<int> &` and x to any ``std::vector &,std::vector &&,const std::vector &` by writing

```
template<class T2,         
std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<std::decay_t<T2>,std::vector<int>>,bool> = true>        
void foo(T2 && a, const std::vector<int> & b){}
```

Comment: From your last paragraph it seems like you don't need to copy (and thus not modify) the arguments. So why not define a single function with both `const &` arguments?

Comment: Templates solve this problem.

Comment: Your edit completely changes the question! If you sometimes have to modify the input, then `// Do something` is **not** exactly the same. So which is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of writing four overloads, you can do this with a single function template.  Doing that would give you a function like

```
template <typename Vec1, typename Vec2,
          std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<std::decay_t<Vec1>, std::vector<int>> &&
                           std::is_same_v<std::decay_t<Vec2>, std::vector<int>>, bool> = true>
double foo(Vec1&& x, Vec2&& y)
{
    // stuff
}
```

Now `x` and `y` can be an lvalue or rvalue `std::vector<int>`, and `const` or not.

Comment: Can I force one of x or y to be `const`, e.g. by writing `double foo(Vec1&& x, const Vec2&& y)` ?

Comment: @Ethanabc No. This allows one or both to be `const`, but you can't explicitly call out for it.  If you do, you no longer have a forwarding reference but just an rvalue reference.

Answer (score 7):

Since the functions all do the same thing, they clearly do not modify the inputs. In that case, don't even bother with the rvalue references and instead just use `const` lvalues references. I.e., this is the only function you need:

```cpp
double foo(const std:::vector<int> & x, const std:::vector<int> & y){
// Do something
}
```

Temporaries will bind to `const` lvalue references, so this one function can handle both temporaries and non-temporaries.

Comment: can temporaries also bind to lvalue referece?

Comment: Only if it's `const`.